# How to add javaFaker in katalon studio project?

Tags: selenium, gradle, katalon-studio

I am trying to automate a process where a user will register to an application by filling up a form which contains many fields(12). And multiple user registration will be done at a time. But each time the email and a couple of other information must be unique. I am trying to implement javafaker as it makes to process lot easier. I've done it previously in the maven project. But now I'm working in katalon-studio. I tried to add the dependency in the "build.gradle" file but not working.

Comment: What did you do after adding it to your build.gradle file ?

Comment: What did your build.gradle file look like?